# Trying To Create Search system Using Eloquent , Slim3 Framework. And Ajax

Tags: php, model-view-controller, slim

I'm In MVC and starting builing a web app using slim 3 framework but stucked  in search system.
i almost created the search system but it shows only 1 result like i have 2 users with same similar names.
1 is John Doe And second is John Carter. when i write john it shows only 1 user not both.

Route:

```
$app->post('/search/users', 'SearchController:searchusers' )->setName('search.query.users');
```

Controller :

```
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Profile;
use App\Models\Workplace;
use App\Controllers\Controller;
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;
use Slim\Views\Twig as View;


class SearchController extends Controller{
public function searchusers($request, $response, $args){

    $queryinput = $request->getParam('query');

    $search = User::where('user_displayname', 'LIKE' ,"%{$queryinput}%")
        ->leftJoin('wp_profile', 'wp_users.id', '=', 'wp_profile.profile_account_id');

    $users = $search->get();
    $count = $search->count();

    if($count > 0){
        foreach($users as $user){
            $response = array(
                'fullname' => $user->user_displayname,
                'username' => $user->user_login,
                'occupation' => $user->profile_occupation,
                'location' => $user->profile_country . ', ' . $user->profile_city,
                'avatar' => $user->profile_avatar
            );

        }


        return json_encode($response);


    }
}
}
```

AJAX Jquery:

```
(function($){

    $('#query').keyup(function () {
        var query = $(this).val().length;
        if(query == 0){
            $('.result').addClass('d-none');
        }else{
            $('.result').removeClass('d-none');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url : basepath + '/search/users',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                query : $(this).val()
            },
            success : function (data){
                console.log(data);
                
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                
                var check = jQuery.isEmptyObject(data);
                var output = '';
                if(check){
                    output = 'No Result Found';
                }
                 output = '<a href="'+basepath+'/u/'+response.username+'" class="search-media"><div class="search-mediabox media py-2 px-2 rounded-lg"> <div class="search-avatar mt-2"><img src="'+basepath+'/media/storage/img/'+response.avatar+'" alt="Generic placeholder image"></div> <div class="media-body pl-2"> <h5 class="m-0">'+response.fullname+'</h5> <p class="p-0 m-0">From <b>'+response.location+'</b> - <b>'+response.occupation+'</b></p> </div> </div></a>';
          
                
                $('.result').html(output);
            }

        })

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Can any one tell me why it show only 1 record?

Comment: Eloquent and Slim? Did you mix them?

Comment: In your `foreach` loop you're overwriting `$response = array(...` on every iteration, last one wins

Comment: yes eloquent and slim i follow a tutorial on yt 
any solution?

Comment: i think i didn't loop in js?

Comment: Not in JS, in PHP: `foreach($users as $user){...`

Comment: issue is resolved.